# Array.prototype.find() - Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading x)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a Typescript project in which I have an array of objects from which I want to extract the value of a key where another value matches the local variable.

I need to get the value of `sheetId` of the object where the value of `title` is equal to the value of `fileName`

This is my object:

```
let list = [
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 1000297558,
      "title": "ser"
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 24134863,
      "title": "atr"
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 668935915,
      "title": "work"
    }
  }
]
```

This is the variable:

```
let fileName = 'atr'
```

This is what I want to get:

```
let testId = 24134863
```

This is what I am doing, but I only get it to show me true in the object that matches, but I don't know how to extract the key:

```
let sheetFile = list.map((elem: any) => elem.properties.title == fileName)
```

**Update**:

This is what I'm doing to find the value of sheetId:

```
let sheetId: number = list.find((elem: any) => elem.properties.title == fileName).properties.sheetId
```

This is the error it shows:

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
```

My problem: how can I control that undefined or how can I assign it a 0, for example so that it has a value

Comment: just a quick note, you don't need that :any after map. It is typescript, it will know what it is. Also you could have easily found answers for your question.

Comment: It's still the same method like in the previous version of this question. [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object (`properties` and `title` still seem to be fixed values) and then just read the `sheetId` property of the found object -> [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: @Andreas Yes, but I am trying different operations on the array and now I was looking in case the variable does not exist in the array, how to return a null or something so as not to produce an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.find` method to find and extract your value with dot notation.

```js
const fileName = 'atr'
const list = [
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 1000297558,
      "title": "ser"
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 24134863,
      "title": "atr"
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 668935915,
      "title": "work"
    }
  }
]

const result = list.find((item) => item.properties.title === fileName).properties.sheetId;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How can I make this function return null in case the variable does not exist inside the array?

Comment: @main Replace the **result** variable to this
`const result = list.find((item) => item.properties.title === fileName)?.properties.sheetId ?? null;`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to `filter` to find matches.

After that, extract (with `map`) from the previous matches.

```js
let list = [
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 1000297558,
      "title": "ser"
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 24134863,
      "title": "atr"
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 668935915,
      "title": "work"
    }
  }
]

let fileName = 'atr'

let testId = 24134863

let sheetFile = list
  .filter((elem) => elem.properties.title == fileName)
  .map((elem) => elem.properties.sheetId)
 
console.log(sheetFile)
```